# How to cast to a private inner class when type information is unavailable?

Tags: java, class, reflection, private

I have a situation similar to the following:

```
// In some library code
public class A
{
    private class B
    {
        Object value;
    }
}

// In my code
Object o;

// o is initialized to an instance of B somehow
// ...

B bInstance = (B) o;
```

How would I go about casting an Object to type B **given that the type of B is inaccessible**?

To explain in more detail, A is *not* part of my code base.  It's part of a library.  I have access to an object that I know is of type B, but I can't cast it (in an IDE, for example) because the type information is not visible.  It's a compilation error.  The situation is very restrictive. I think it might be possible to achieve this using reflection, but I'm afraid I don't have a lot of experience using that particular paradigm.  Is there any way around this? I appreciate any input the community would offer.

Comment: One thing about using private inner classes is exactly that you don't want other people to use it. Why are you going this way? What's the issue at hand?

Comment: Is there some method you want to invoke on your `B` instance? You could just use `toString()`, or you could use reflection to invoke an arbitrary method in B through it's instance.

Comment: This is working correctly. I assume B implements some interface, since you have a reference to it. What are you trying to do that the interface reference is not sufficient?

Comment: Cast to an interface that B implements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe there is an interface you should be accesing instead? Or is it inaccesible too?

I don't know whether the following is what you need, but maybe this can help you find a workaround (since you asked for uses of reflection):

Since you somehow have your B instance you should try:

```
Class<?> innerClass = o.getClass();
```

And then if possible, try to get what you need by using reflection like this:

```
Field allFields[] = innerClass.getDeclaredFields();    
Constructor<?> constructors[] = innerClass.getDeclaredConstructors();
Method allMethods[] = innerClass.getDeclaredMethods();

constructor.setAccessible(true);  sets the constructor accessible.
```

Can you instantiate the instance yourself or is it important to use the one somehow returned?

Comment: In this particular case, there was a public interface that I could use.  For some reason that never actually crossed my mind. Thank you!